# Get a value from a prepared statment using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch only one value of returned row .. here's what i have tried

```
function getUserEmail($username) {
global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username =? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userEmail = $stmt->fetch_object()->useremail;

    return $userEmail;
}
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()
```

what I'm looking for is only getting the user's email no need to fetch other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_stmt](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) doesn't have a method `fetch_object`, but [mysqli_result](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) does.
see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php